# Segmentation fault in CGAL when intersecting polygons

Tags: c++, polygon, computational-geometry, overlap, cgal

I'm writing a code where I need to calculate the overlapping area of two polygons very frequently (one always is a square, the other one is a simple but in general non-convex polygon). However, using CGAL for this, I occasionally encounter segmentation faults. The following code provides a minimal example. Note that as soon as one of the point coordinates is moved by 0.001, everything works fine.

```
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_with_holes_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2_algorithms.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<K> PolygonH;

int main()
{    
     // Rectangle
     Point pointsA[] = { Point(0.4,0.35), Point(0.4,0.4), Point(0.45,0.4), Point(0.5,0.35) };

     // Triangle
     Point pointsB[] = { Point(0.428,0.412), Point(0.387,0.389), Point(0.359,0.393) };

     // Convert to CGAL polygon
     Polygon polyA(pointsA, pointsA + 4);
     Polygon polyB(pointsB, pointsB + 3);

     // Intersection
     std::list<PolygonH> polyAB;
     CGAL::intersection(polyA, polyB, std::back_inserter(polyAB));
}
```

Comment: Looks like a CGAL bug to me.

Comment: If you compile in debug mode, instead of a crash you get an assertion failure that says: "The polygon has a wrong orientation". By the way, `Cartesian<double>` is a bad idea.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Reversing the orientations of either of two (or even both) polygons, doesn't help, though. In this case debug mode still throws some "precondition violation". Also could you please elaborate on your statement of `Cartesian<double>` being a bad idea? I'm kind of a CGAL novice and just took it from some example

Comment: If I reverse the orientation of both polygons, this specific assertion disappears (please don't do the novice error of assuming that all error messages are equivalent). Another one appears which is due to your choice of kernel and is fixed using `typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first polygon is always convex (as most squares are) and you only care for the area of overlap, you can roll your own solution easily.

Consider the support line of one of the sides of the first polygon. You will implement clipping against a half plane, let us assume bounded by x=0, WLOG.

Create an empty output polygon. Then try all edges of the second polygon in turn. Assign every vertex the boolean condition x>=0. If the condition is different for both endpoints, append the intersection of the side with the axis x=0 to the new polygon; then if the condition is true for the final endpoint of the side, append it as well.

In the end, you'll get a new polygon which is the clipped version of the original. In case the clipped polygon should be disconnected, the algorithm will produce a connected polygon with extra connecting sides along x=0. But as regards the computation of the area, this doesn't matter at all.

Repeat with the four clipping sides and compute the area using the shoelace formula.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! However, the algorithm won't give the correct result if the two polygons are either _disjoint_ or the clipping polygon is entirely _inside_ the other polygon. Unfortunately both scenarios may occur in my case ...

Comment: @Beaker: why do you say that ? The method is bulletproof for these cases. It is actually bulletproof for anything, even overlapping sides and vertices, crossed and degenerate polygons...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, of course you are right. Thank you for pointing out this neat solution!